# How to make gui based setup of git server?

Tags: git

I have 1 git server and few  systems(git installed)  connected to server. I'm trying to setup a gui based setup for server and clients systems both. I'm have Ubuntu on all systems. Could anyone help me in this regard? Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: What do you mean by gui based setup? Are you talking about git-gui ? git-gui is an application which can be used on the client computer. What have you installed on the server? gitosis?

Comment: To khaja

I have installed git-core on both server and clients systems not gitosis.From the term gui based i mean i want to work in a graphical interface and not on the command promp with commands.You may be right may be it is git-gui.

Answer (score 3):

For a GUI based setup, you may try [cgit](http://hjemli.net/git/cgit/). Here is a [tutorial](http://www.codeography.com/2009/05/30/setting-up-cgit-under-ubuntu.html) for setting up cgit in ubuntu.

Comment: There is also an opensource GITHUB CLONE released recently http://www.gitlabhq.com/

Answer (score 1):

WHat is "GUI based setup"? In its core, "git clients" and "git servers" (for real GIT is distributed system, not so much "central server" and "clients" exists unlike in SVN or CVS, but for sure you can treat a GIT repository as the "master one") communicate through the network, so no "GUI" is needed here. What you can do in GUI: you can have GUI to work on your repository (even maybe integrated into your IDE) or some kind of "GUI" (let's say a web based one) where you can examine the content of the repository. If you mean this, you may need (of course you can find more!) gitweb. It's in the Ubuntu's repositories (can be installed with apt-get) and written as perl. It acts a CGI solution. More information: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb

Answer (score 0):

seems gitorious is the best option

Comment: @lenzai Even better, you could expand this answer to explain how to install and use gitorious (and to include links to more detailed sources of information).

Comment: I am sorry guys, that was my best pick while googling by the time I was planing git server. Since then I have given up setting up and I am currently using Saas at http://bitbucket.org .